# Что означает фраза: "Натянуть на ВордПресс"?

Tags: cms

Что означает фраза: "Натянуть на ВордПресс"?

Comment: Это значит с html/css исходников сделать шаблон для cms WordPress

Comment: Древняя кавказская угроза. Примерно как "я твой дом труба шатал"